# Timezone Conversion moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a requirement to convert (UTC/GMT) time to local time based on timezone string provided by user using moment js.
Eg:

```
utctime = "2014-06-09T05:36:06.005Z"
timezone = "5.5" (Indian Standard Time)
expected result = "2014-06-09 11:06"
```

I have tried some code to achieve this

```
var local_date = moment.utc("2014-06-09T05:36:06.005Z").zone("+05:30").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
console.log('local date', local_date); // 2014-06-09 11:06
```

Here am getting correct result. But i have to put time zone in +05:30 format when i put "5.5"(timzone format am getting from user side) its not working at all.

Am getting user time zone like the following way

```
-12, -11, .... -1 GMT 1, 2 .. 3.3, 5, 5.5, 5.75 ...
```

Is there any way to convert GMT time to local using above timezone format. Please guide me in right direction. If it is not possible how can i covert the user input time zone to my desired format. Thank you

Comment: Can't you create a function to directly replace the received timezone format with the one you want? (5.5 -> "05:30", etc...).

Comment: That is my last choice. But before that i don't know is there any direct function in moment js to do that. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can find the function in the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/ . Eg: `moment().zone(minutesSinceGMT)`. This way you only have to `multiply` the received number by `60`.

Comment: try using var yourvalue=parseFloat("5.5"); moment.utc("2014-06-09T05:36:06.005Z").add('hours',yourvalue).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8qtFy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help you http://jsfiddle.net/8qtFy/

```
var yourvalue=parseFloat("5.5");        

moment.utc("2014-06-09T05:36:06.005Z").add('hours',yourvalue).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```